# Java Programming Help: Trouble with If statement direction

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have worked up a code for testing leap years but wish to add an amendment to dictate if it is in the past or not. Toward that end I have added a condition that if the input happens to be 2012 or greater then the present tense proves true otherwise it assumes the past tense. As it stands it ignores this qualifier however and just executes the first statement. Any help in finishing this up would be appreciated.

*code noted below*

```
{
    int input;

    System.out.println("Enter year:");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (input >= 2012){

    if ((input%4==0) && input%100!= 0)
    {
        System.out.println(input + " is a leap year.");
    }
    else if (input%400==0)
    {
        System.out.println(input + " is a leap year.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(input + " is not a leap year.");
      }
}
    while (input < 2012){

    if ((input%4==0) && input%100!= 0)
    {
        System.out.println(input + " was a leap year.");
    }
    else if (input%400==0)
    {
        System.out.println(input + " was a leap year.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(input + " was not a leap year.");
    }
}

}
}
```

Comment: your while loops will never finish

Answer (score 0):

i think u r wrong here- `while (input >= 2012)`
use `if` instead of `while`  i.e.`if (input >= 2012)` 
also `if (input <= 2012)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not really know what while loops are for. It is a loop, meaning it repeats until the condition is not satisfied. An example:

```
x=10
while(x!=0){ int dosomething = 1; x--}
```

This loop repeats 10 times. So simply change your while's to if's and the code should work just fine.

Comment: and remember that you need a way to exit this loop(in this case it is x--)